# Why NSubstitute returns only last value when multiples are specified

Tags: c#, mocking, nsubstitute

I am trying to mock IDbConnection in my DAO class, but I am receiving following error:

**String lengths are both 5. Strings differ at index 0.
  Expected: "11111"
  But was:  "22222"**

Here is my code:

*Classes under test*

```
internal class ImportAcquisitionDataDAO : IImportAcquisitionDataDAO
{
    private static Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    private readonly IDbConnection connection;

    internal ImportAcquisitionDataDAO(IDbConnection connection)
    {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    internal List<DefinitionEntry> GetDefinitions()
    {
        log.Debug("Getting definitions from database.");

        var definitions = new List<DefinitionEntry>();

        using (connection)
        {
            connection.Open();
            log.Trace("Database connection opened");

            IDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = @"SELECT *
                                    FROM MAPPING";

            IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            log.Trace("Command executed:\n{0}", command.CommandText);

            definitions = GetMeterEntries(reader);
        }

        log.Debug("Obtained {0} definitions.", definitions.Count);
        return definitions;         
    }

    private List<DefinitionEntry> GetMeterEntries(IDataReader reader)
    {
        log.Trace("Parsing definitions from response");

        var result = new List<DefinitionEntry>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var definition = new DefinitionEntry(
                reader.GetString(0),
                reader.GetString(1),
                reader.GetString(2),
                reader.IsDBNull(3) ? null : reader.GetString(3),
                reader.IsDBNull(4) ? null : reader.GetString(4),
                reader.IsDBNull(5) ? null : reader.GetString(5),
                reader.IsDBNull(6) ? null : reader.GetString(6)
                );

            log.Trace(definition.ToString());
            result.Add(definition);
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class DefinitionEntry
{
    public string MeterSN { get; private set; }
    public string MATNR { get; private set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; private set; }
    public string SIM { get; private set; }
    public string ModulID { get; private set; }
    public string SIMUser { get; private set; }
    public string SIMPassword { get; private set; }

    public DefinitionEntry(string meterSN, string matnr, string ipAddress, string sim, string modulId, string simUser, string simPassword)
    {
        MeterSN = meterSN;
        MATNR = matnr;
        IpAddress = ipAddress;
        SIM = sim;
        ModulID = modulId;
        SIMUser = simUser;
        SIMPassword = simPassword;
    }
}
```

*Test class*

```
[TestFixture]
public class ImportAcquisitionDataDAOTests
{
    private IDbConnection mockConnection;
    private IDbCommand mockCommand;
    private IDataReader mockReader;
    private ImportAcquisitionDataDAO dao;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        mockConnection = Substitute.For<IDbConnection>();
        mockCommand = Substitute.For<IDbCommand>();
        mockReader = Substitute.For<IDataReader>();
        dao = new ImportAcquisitionDataDAO(mockConnection);

        mockConnection.CreateCommand().Returns(mockCommand);
        mockCommand.ExecuteReader().Returns(mockReader);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestGetDefinitions()
    {
        // mock
        var databaseDefinitionFirst = new DefinitionEntry("11111", "AS3000-5/100-400-P", "10.42.42.26", "SIM-001", "12345lkj", "alibaba", "abrakadabra");
        var databaseDefinitionSecond = new DefinitionEntry("22222", "AS3000-5/100-400-Q", "10.42.42.158", null, null, null, null);

        mockReader.Read().Returns(true, true, false);
        mockReader.GetString(Arg.Is<int>(0)).Returns(databaseDefinitionFirst.MeterSN, databaseDefinitionSecond.MeterSN);
        mockReader.GetString(Arg.Is<int>(1)).Returns(databaseDefinitionFirst.MATNR, databaseDefinitionSecond.MATNR);
        mockReader.GetString(Arg.Is<int>(2)).Returns(databaseDefinitionFirst.IpAddress, databaseDefinitionSecond.IpAddress);
        mockReader.IsDBNull(Arg.Is<int>(3)).Returns(false, true);
        mockReader.GetString(Arg.Is<int>(3)).Returns(databaseDefinitionFirst.SIM);
        mockReader.IsDBNull(Arg.Is<int>(4)).Returns(false, true);
        mockReader.GetString(Arg.Is<int>(4)).Returns(databaseDefinitionFirst.ModulID);
        mockReader.IsDBNull(Arg.Is<int>(5)).Returns(false, true);
        mockReader.GetString(Arg.Is<int>(5)).Returns(databaseDefinitionFirst.SIMUser);
        mockReader.IsDBNull(Arg.Is<int>(6)).Returns(false, true);
        mockReader.GetString(Arg.Is<int>(6)).Returns(databaseDefinitionFirst.SIMPassword);

        // use
        List<DefinitionEntry> tested = dao.GetDefinitions();

        // verify
        Assert.AreEqual(2, tested.Count);
        AssertDefinitionEntry(databaseDefinitionFirst, tested.First());
        AssertDefinitionEntry(databaseDefinitionSecond, tested.Last());
    }

    private void AssertDefinitionEntry(DefinitionEntry expected, DefinitionEntry tested)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.MeterSN, tested.MeterSN);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.MATNR, tested.MATNR);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.IpAddress, tested.IpAddress);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.SIM, tested.SIM);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.ModulID, tested.ModulID);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.SIMUser, tested.SIMUser);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.SIMPassword, tested.SIMPassword);
    }
}
```

And here is debug screen before first Assert is executed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HSTB.png)

I all is set as I expect except of MeterSN field, which is same for both entries. But I am not able to find out why

Comment: Can you provide as concise as possible example please. You will more likely get an answer.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I agree that code should be as concise as possible but on the other hand I wanted to keep code "complete" so anyone can reproduce same code behavior. I can remove logging which takes few lines however from my point of view code is long but there is not complex logic and it is quite easy to get meaning from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is quite a subtle problem.

Short answer:

Move `mockReader.GetString(Arg.Is<int>(0)).Returns(databaseDefinitionFirst.MeterSN, databaseDefinitionSecond.MeterSN);` to be the last call stubbed (just under `mockReader.GetString(Arg.Is<int>(6))`).

Longer answer:

When we say `mockReader.GetString(Arg.Is<int>(5))`, the `Arg.Is` part returns zero, which means `mockReader.GetString(0)` gets called several times within the test setup. So "11111" does get returned first as configured, but by the time the `GetDefinitions` gets called that value has already been used consumed.

---

Incidentally, NSubstitute treats `mockReader.GetString(5).Returns(...)` the same as `mockReader.GetString(Arg.Is<int>(5))`, which will simplify your code a little.

As another aside, I would suggest trying to find a way to [use a real data reader in your tests](http://www.davesquared.net/2011/04/dont-mock-types-you-dont-own.html). Something like the following would let you avoid mocking out the details of that type:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(
            new [] {
                new DataColumn("a", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("b", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("c", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("d", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("e", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("f", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("g", typeof(string))
            });
        dt.Rows.Add("11111", "AS3000-5/100-400-P", "10.42.42.26", "SIM-001", "12345lkj", "alibaba", "abrakadabra");
        dt.Rows.Add("22222", "AS3000-5/100-400-Q", "10.42.42.158", null, null, null, null);
        mockReader = new DataTableReader(dt);
```

Then you can remove all the mock setup from your test. With a bit of tweaking (say, some helper methods for doing things like automatically populating the reader given expected objects like `databaseDefinitionFirst`) this could form a nice way of testing all your code that interacts with readers, rather than having to fake everything out all the time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and attached link. I have made the change and now test passes. The article was edifying for me.